# MySQL: Ownership of mysql directory changes to 'mysql' from 'service_account' on linux server reboot

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, mariadb, file-ownership

I'm using MySQL distribution 10.2.39-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64). It runs fine when we initially start it up and manually configure it to correct ownership and startup. But whenever we reboot the Linux server, the ownership of '/var/lib/mysql' changes from 'service_account' to 'mysql', as shown below:

**Before reboot of Linux Server**

```
drwxr-xr-x. service_account service-account_grp 4096 Mar 18 14:00 mysql
```

to

**After reboot of Linux Server**

```
drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql 4096 Mar 18 14:00 mysql
```

It changes ownership itself and I don't happen to find the root cause for it.
I've been facing this issue and I'm not able to find a solution to it.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Sid

Comment: Please, what distribution is? Can you post the contents of `systemctl cat mysql`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030085/mariadb-manjaro-ownership-of-datadir-is-reset-to-mysqlmysql-after-every-reboo/67030213#67030213

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this answer because I think we both have misunderstood the [User Account Management](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-account-management/) mechanisms of mariadb. I have also encountered the [same problem as you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030085/ownership-of-datadir-is-reset-to-mysqlmysql-after-every-reboot), so I'm writing this answer for myself somewhat. You can follow this answer or [danblack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67030213/15003321)'s, whichever you actually need. As danblack said, it may not be a good idea to change "mysql" to your service_account.

Initialize mariadb database directory with 'mysql' user account :

```
$ sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
...
Two all-privilege accounts were created.
One is root@localhost, it has no password, but you need to
be system 'root' user to connect. Use, for example, sudo mysql
The second is mysql@localhost, it has no password either, but
you need to be the system 'mysql' user to connect.
After connecting you can set the password, if you would need to be
able to connect as any of these users with a password and without sudo
...
```

As you can see, two mariadb all-privilege accounts, `root@localhost` and `mysql@localhost`, were created. And you must be operating system `root` and `mysql` user to use these two mariadb accounts, respectively.

After then, enable and start mariadb server :

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now mariadb.service
```

You may want to use `mysql_secure_installation` command to [improve the initial security](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB#Improve_initial_security).

Then use mariadb `root@localhost` account with system `root` account to connect to sever, and [create new mariadb account that has root-like privileges](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#granting-root-like-privileges) with whatever name you want:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p  # first input your passwd to use 'sudo', then [ENTER] for empty mariadb root account passwd
[sudo] password for your_service_account:
Enter password:
...
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'whatever_name_you_want'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepasswd';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.004 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'whatever_name_you_want'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.004 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> quit
Bye
```

Use new unprivileged `whatever_name_you_want@localhost` account to connect to server and create a new database :

```
$ mysql -u whatever_name_you_want -p
Enter password:
...
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> quit
Bye
```

And if you set password for `root@localhost` account, you can even use this account without sudo :

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
[sudo] password for your_service_account:
Enter password:
...
MariaDB [(none)]> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('somepasswd');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.041 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> quit
Bye
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
...
MariaDB [(none)]> quit
Bye
```