# Ownership of datadir is reset to mysql:mysql after every reboot

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.5.9-1 on Manjaro 5.10.23-1.

I initialized mariadb database directory using this command:

```
$ sudo mariadb-install-db --user=shaouai --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

After data directory initialization, permissions and ownership of `/var/lib/mysql`:

```
$ ls -ld /var/lib/mysql
drwx------ 5 shaouai root 4096 Apr 10 00:08 mysql
$ ls -lh /var/lib/mysql
total 109M
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai  24K Apr 10 00:08 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai   52 Apr 10 00:08 aria_log_control
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai  972 Apr 10 00:08 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai  12M Apr 10 00:08 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai  96M Apr 10 00:08 ib_logfile0
drwx------ 2 shaouai shaouai 4.0K Apr 10 00:08 mysql
drwx------ 2 shaouai shaouai 4.0K Apr 10 00:08 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 shaouai shaouai 4.0K Apr 10 00:08 test
```

And there's one another directory `/run/mysqld`, which file `mysqld.sock` resides in by default when server is up and running, has permissions and ownership:

```
$ ls -ld /run/mysqld/
drwxr-xr-x 2 shaouai shaouai 60 Apr 10 08:31 /run/mysqld/
```

I have no idea when `/run/mysqld` was created, maybe the first time server started successfully.

`mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql` can start server successfully.

But the problem is, after every reboot, the permissions and ownership of `/var/lib/mysql` and `/run/mysqld` was reset to `mysql:mysql` :

```
$ ls -ld /var/lib/mysql
drwx------ 5 mysql mysql 4096 Apr 10 00:08 mysql
$ ls -lh /var/lib/mysql
total 109M
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai  24K Apr 10 00:08 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai   52 Apr 10 00:08 aria_log_control
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai  972 Apr 10 00:08 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai  12M Apr 10 00:08 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 shaouai shaouai  96M Apr 10 00:08 ib_logfile0
drwx------ 2 shaouai shaouai 4.0K Apr 10 00:08 mysql
drwx------ 2 shaouai shaouai 4.0K Apr 10 00:08 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 shaouai shaouai 4.0K Apr 10 00:08 test
$ ls -ld /run/mysqld/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 60 Apr 10 08:31 /run/mysqld/
```

Thus due to various "permission denied", MariaDB server failed to start.

There's one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66698473/mysql-ownership-of-mysql-directory-changes-to-mysql-from-service-account-on) totally the same as mine.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/dushaoshuai/0e784bb4164e4944c1bf014daf02fee3) is full output of `systemctl cat mariadb.service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you changed the user. It may not be a good idea. But assuming there is a good reason, below explains your situtation:

It looks like the mysqld_safe may have changed the permissions. If you start this way for testing add `--user=shaouai` to the arguments.

To allow systemd to default start as the user `shaouai`

`systemctl edit mariadb.service`

Add:

```
[Service]
User=shaouai
Group=shaouai
```

Then:

```
chown -R shaouai: /var/lib/mysql /run/mysqld/
```

Then `systemctl restart mariadb.service`.

This will start the service as this user instead of the default `mysql` user.

Comment: I changed "mysql" to my user name because I thought I have to login as the system "mysql" user to connect the server, just as "The second is mysql@localhost, it has no password either, but you need to be the system 'mysql' user to connect" indicated. Am I totally wrong ?

Comment: If I can connect to the sever and don't have to be the system "mysql" user, I'll just initialize datadir with "mysql". Now I think it's totally possible according to your words. I'm so grateful.

Comment: Yes, a mysql@localhost with [unix socket auth](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#security). Use `show create user` to display the current user and `show create user root@localhost` to show another user. `select user,host from mysql.user` shows the current users. You can create your own users with [create user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/). All of these are independent to what user the database is running as.

Comment: A lot of thanks @danblack. I've written my answer in which I initialized datadir with "mysql", the link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67032184/15003321) if you like.